# Python or Node.js for a Web app which interfaces with a USB devices?

Tags: python, node.js, dll, web-applications

I'm looking to develop a web app that controls Concept2 rowing gym equipment connected to the users computer via USB. I'm trying to decide what approach I should take in developing something like this.

Control of these devices has been achieved in the past both in python:
(https://github.com/uvd/PyRow)
and using node/jQuery:
(https://github.com/tijmenvangulik/ErgometerJS).

An SDK and documentation is provided by the developers of Concept2 gym equipment. DLL and CSafe commands are used to interface with the machines monitors. 
(https://www.concept2.com/service/software/software-development-kit)

I'm looking for recommendations on how I should this tackle this project. At the moment python seems like the best approach however I have no idea how I can run these python files through a website interacting with the java script front end.

Any advice or pointers is appreciated.

David

Answer (score 0):

You task looks like a simple SCADA solution with web interface.

You choice depends on whether you have experienced developers, who are able to use modern frameworks like `Vue.js`, `Angular`, `React` and others or not.

Really, in your particular case - monitoring equipment over web, you don't necessary need to invest a lot in your front-end - depends on your target audience. Is it a single service engineer? If **yes**, probably your front-end should be minimalistic, you can use Python with `Twisted` for static web server and build your frontend on `bootstrap` plus `jquery`. This is a fast win solution and you can implement it even if you've never worked with web.

More complex approach, requiring more engineering, is `Python` + `Flask`.

If you feel ready for modern frameworks, like Vue, React, Angular, then, possibly, you'd better look at NodeJs as a backend. They are better integrated with NodeJs and its package manager `npm`. You will need it to build the project on your server side; also some people treat it as a **solid** solution, when using the same language (`javascript`) for both backend and frontend. As for me, it doesn't really matter a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am the developer and I don't have any experience with any frameworks, only javascript itself. I don't mind learning one however as that's the point in this project. For now the the front end will be minimal. Using NodeJs sounds like a good approach and will research twisted and flask as the python approach to this problem is already working.

Comment: Then consider `bootstrap` + `jquery` for front end. They will give you pretty looking UI  in a moment. After getting some experience, you can move to more complex MVCs, like Vue, e.g. That was exactly our development path